# <Base> link with port number for HTML

Tags: html

I'm facing the following:

I set up a dynamic DNS connection to my home and forwarded a port number 80xx to my NAS's 80 port, so I can access it from remote.

When I fill the login form and try to login, it points to the address without the port number, so I have to manually modify the address in the browser bar to re-add the port number.

The form is set like this: `<form action="/" method="post" name="login" id="login">`

How can I modify the page in order to get it working from remote, **as well as from local** (accessed on standard port 80), without the need to manually modify the address?

Early in my "develop-life", I heard about the `<base>` but I'm not sure on how using it to get the page working **in both configurations**.

Thanks

Comment: What server-side language are you in, php?

Comment: If I remember well, yes. It should, since it runs linux.

Comment: `base` is HTML. Nothing to do with `PHP`.

Comment: I don't want a `<base>`-based solution at any costs :) any solution  would be good for me.

Comment: Right, I asked about server-side because that's the solution to this problem.  I'll form an answer.

Comment: If the `action` attribute doesn't specify an origin the browser should assume the origin the page was requested on so the scenario you describe should not be happening. Are you sure the port is not being specified somewhere else. Is the response to posting the form issuing a 302 redirect with a Location header that specifies a port?

Comment: @SamGreenhalgh Yes probably something like that is happening. In fact, when the error page appears, the login is actually already done. Adding the port on the address bar, just take you to the logged-in interface. What should I look for in the PHP to discover if a redirect is made?

Comment: What is the NAS software you're using?

Comment: @SamGreenhalgh It's a WD MyBook World. I already know where the web-interface PHP files are stored, I also made some modding in past. Could you tell me which PHP statement should I look for?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not a PHP dev, but I expect what you are looking for is the `header` method being used to set the `Location` header - http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: @SamGreenhalgh Exactly, the page is reloaded as self and than a location header is set if the login was successful. Unfurtunately if I put the port in the header it does nothing, in the "network" tab of Chrome the request appears as cancelled.

Comment: @SamGreenhalgh I did it, by passing the correct port via POST and then adding it to the Location header. If you write your suggestion as an answer, I'd accept and award bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment

> If the action attribute doesn't specify an origin the browser should
>   assume the origin the page was requested on so the scenario you
>   describe should not be happening. Are you sure the port is not being
>   specified somewhere else. Is the response to posting the form issuing
>   a 302 redirect with a Location header that specifies a port?

For others readers - Setting the port number in the form action and the redirected location header should solve the problem.

Comment: Accepted and upvoted, I'm afraid I can't award the bounty, but the grace period was just expired when you wrote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have php, a possible solution would be to detect the port, and if it's not 80, to include it as the form action.

```
<?
//use intval to be a little more secure
var port =  intval($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']);
var url="http://fullurl.com/";
if(!port==80){
   url="http://fullrul.com:".port."/";
}
?>
```

you can then print your form as:

```
 <form action="<?php echo url; ?>" method="post" name="login" id="login">
```

As long as you enter with the port in your url, it will print to the form as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately SERVER_PORT is always 80, probably because the router forwards the incoming 80xx to 80.

Comment: Looking serverside the form code is: `<form action="<?=($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>" method="post" name="login" id="login">
`

Comment: if the router is doing forwarding, then you may be able to trap it with the `X_FORWARDED_FOR` header.   Do a `print_r($_SERVER)`and see what you have available for headers.

Comment: As the router is using NAT to forward packets on IP level, looking for a X_FORWARDED_FOR header wont help. This header is set by proxies, not routers.